# C socket read all function possible wrong?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a client/server program using sockets, with protobuf messages, for school.

However one of the commands is(put) isn't working properly. It works with size, and returns 0, as it should but when I try put, it doesn't seem to work properly. I wrote some printf's in the code to try and check what's happening, and read_all doesn't seem right.

Here's the code.

```
int read_all (int socket, char *buf, int len){
    int left;
    int used;
    char *prov;
    prov = buf;
    left = len;
    printf("read all len: %d\n",len);
    while (left > 0) {
        printf("left : %d\n",left);
        used = read(socket, prov, left);
        printf("used: %d\n",used);
        if ( used  < 0) {
            perror("readall err\n");
            printf("errno here %d \n",errno);
            return -1;
        } else if (used == 0) break;

        left -= used;
        printf("left 2 : %d\n",left);
        prov += used;
    }
    printf("read_all %d\n",len-left);
    return (len - left);
}
```

When I use put , on the server terminal it shows :

```
read all len: 6
left: 6
```

and then it stops, that makes me think that read_all isn't working well, but I don't understand why. While on the client terminal it just shows that put wasn't successful.

Is read_all right or is something wrong.

Edit,  read calls.

```
read_all for the size of msg buff:
read_all(client_socket, &rec, sizeof(rec) )

read_all for msg buff:
read_all(client_socket,(char *) rbuf, len )
```

rec is an int

len is an unsigned  = ntohl(rec)

rbuf is a uint8_t = malloc(len)

edit 3:

write_all code:

```
int write_all(int socket, char *buf, int len){
    int bufsize = len;
    char *prov = buf;
    while(bufsize > 0){

        int res = write(socket, prov, bufsize);

        if(res < 0){
            perror("writeall err");
            return -1;
        }

        prov += res;
        bufsize -= res;
    }
    return len;
}
```

write calls:

```
sends size:
write_all(descr, &sen , sizeof(len))) != len)

send msg buf:
write_all(descritor,(char *) buf, len)) != len)

variable:
unsigned len = message_t__get_packed_size(msg)
uint8_t *buf = malloc(len)
unsigned sen = htoml(len)
```

Comment: The problem is either with the code that connects the socket or the other end. Your code is calling `read` and then waiting for the other end to send 6 bytes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - In my code I have two write_all in client and two read_all in server, the first write and read all are supposed to send and receive the size of the msg buffer, and the second are supposed to send and receive the msg buffer. Would that be wrong, and the first read all is reading both write? The thing that confuses me the most tho is that when I try the size command it works well. I send the buffer size first and the msg first and there's no error but when I try to send the put msg this happens.

Comment: What does the first `read` look like? Is it also a call to `read_all` with the size specified being the number of bytes the message size occupies? If not, then it could also read all or part of the message.

Comment: What type is `rec`? What does the corresponding `write` code look like? Are you absolutely sure it writes `sizeof(rec)` bytes?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I added write_all, above write_all is what every variable is, and below the write code is the write call variables.

Comment: I don't see any serious issues with this code. One issue is that `len` is an `int` instead of an `unsigned` to match `rec`. Another is that your `write_all` code will spin endlessly if the connection closes normally while writing. But if these two pieces of code are connected to each other, and the writer writes, I don't see any reason the reader shouldn't read.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So yeah, I've been trying to find out why it doesn't work, and I have no clue. The unsinged len and the int rec, is because it was said on the project that you you could/should send and unsigned first that corresponds to the size of the serialized buffer, before sending the buffer.

Comment: ofc first you'd tried is `send()` / `recv()` ?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин no, at least for the serialized mesage i need the read wrte all, I guess I could try sending the size thorugh send and recv

Comment: when i have to deal with protobuf in golang all this stuff were shipped with it. strange that you need own written stuff for this

Comment: @Isaacovsky – Better post runnable code to reproduce the problem.